# Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources' in Unity

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-install-apk

I am trying to build and run my game project to Android in Unity version 2020.1.0b5.3485.
It is failing after it hits the Gradle section.

I have tried things like deleting .Gradle, letting Android Studio update Grade, and some script edits. Nothing has worked.

My project is nearly completed and ready for Android, but this is blocking me finishing the game. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

**These are all the errors logged in the console, in order:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka com.PreyInteractive.IdleTown:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found. 
(*3)
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka com.PreyInteractive.IdleTown:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
(*3)
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka com.PreyInteractive.IdleTown:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
(*3)
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka com.PreyInteractive.IdleTown:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
(*3)
 error: failed linking references.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
30 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 25 up-to-date
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 79 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0027c] in <92f998fbb4ca4d8dab7793d6e003b794>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <92f998fbb4ca4d8dab7793d6e003b794>:0 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

**Error in Gradle - Android Studio Gradle project**
.gradle is the folder in users/username/...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: The project name '.gradle' must not start or end with a '.'. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement (see https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for more details).

Answer (score -1):

I had a plugin folder that was containing some files that are not compatible with Unity beta 2020. Removing that fixed it.

Comment: Please elaborate with the name of the file/folder and its path